# In DATAGUARD technology, are changes to spfile on PRIMARY propagated to STANDBYs?

Tags: oracle, alter, dataguard, spfile

In DATAGUARD env, how are changes to spfile on PRIMARY propagated to STANDBYs?

e.g. 
I update parameter resource_manager_plan on PRIMARY.
Does the new value also show up for parameter resource_manager_plan on STANDBY?

How to keep initora parameters in-sync between PRIMARY and STANDBY?
Is this a limitation on ALTER SYSTEM command?

PS: I did a ALTER SYSTEM SET of parameter resource_manager_plan on PRIMARY. It did not show up on STANDBY. Logs are applied on standby and standby is up-to-date.

Answer (score 0):

No they're not propagated, and they shouldn't be, because they may have differing settings for primary vs. standby. DB_UNIQUE_NAME, for example.